# United States Military: Should the word "military" be capitalized here?

Tags: capitalization

I have an editor who is going back and forth about whether or not the word
military is capitalized when used in "United States Military".

Comment: *Military* is not a proper name, its a common noun. The proper name for the entity being described is the [*United States Armed Forces*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Armed_Forces). As such, *military* should remain in lowercase. (Unless there is some other context I'm unaware of where it actually is a proper name—or it's being used as part of an entire phrase that's in title case.)

Comment: No, and *U.S. forces* is preferred. (Military is ambiguous -  traditionally, it referred to the Army, later, to the three Military Departments formed in 1947). DoD Dictionary has an entry for *U.S. forces*, but not *U.S. military*.

Comment: The Departments of the Army, of the Navy, and of the Air Force deserve their capital "D" in most combinations.

What warrants the capital "M" in "three Military Departments"?

Isn't that one of the few combinations where the context shifts "department(s)" far enough from their proper use that even the "D" should follow the "M" into lower case?

Answer (score 1):

No. Being generic, the term "military" needs no capital - and nor does "Armed Forces".

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Armed_Forces relies solely on the wholly ambiguous "armed forces - Capitalize only as a proper name (Armed Forces Day) or part of a title or when preceded by U.S., as in U.S. Armed Forces" at  https://www.navy.mil/submit/navyStyleGuide.pdf

(That Wiki… mentions no "armed forces" in explaining the US national command structure and seems unclear even whether the Marine Corps stands alone or is part of the Army or Navy.)

(With apologies to those who see this as disdainful, why should your editor get away with that vacillation? With the best will in the world, grade school should have explained the difference between proper and improper, or common, nouns; high school should have provided the research skills to check either in a paper reference library, or on the internet, to which category "military" belongs.)

Answer (score 0):

No.

The United States is a proper name and should be capitalized. But the military is just something it owns.

Comment: But in the UK, the navy is known as the Royal Navy.